# Doctrine Embeddables that share a common interface

Tags: php, doctrine-orm, doctrine

When using Doctrine Embeddables you have to declare a class on the property like this...

```
/** @Entity */
class User
{
    /** @Embedded(class = "Address") */
    private $address;
}

/** @Embeddable */
class Address
{
}
```

What happens if your property holds a class that implements an interface. So for example... I have a class called Monthly or Weekly that implements an interface called RecurrenceInterface and my entity looks like this...

```
/** @Entity */
class Subscription
{
    /** @var RecurrenceInterface */
    private $recurrence;
}

/** @Embeddable */
class Monthly implements RecurrenceInterface
{
}
```

How do you declare something that implements an interface as an Embeddable?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Doctrines tutorial says that "Embeddables are classes which are not entities themselves". classes and nothing else..

As one of the solutions you can store serialized objects in your entity like this

```
 /**
 * @var Settings\SettingsInterface
 * @ORM\Column(name="settings", type="object")
 */
private $settings;
```

In this case doctrine doesn`t cares what you store there, and you don`t care about serialization/deserialization of stored object.

Also you still have type hinting in your class in setters, getters, on construct etc..

```
 public function __construct(Settings\SettingsInterface $formSettings)
```

There are many obvious disadvantages in this solution, for example, when changing serializable objects